# export google apps user accounts into LDAP

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, ldap, google-apps, openldap

I have a blank LDAP account and want to import all the user accounts from google apps to LDAP and keep the LDAP in sync with google apps (not the other way around using GADS). Is this possible? I need a LDIF file with username and passwords to import into LDAP. Or a csv file?? Please advise.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to get the passwords for your Google Apps users.

You can download a list of all users (in a CSV) right from the Admin console. This will give you the email address, first name and last name. If you need more information than that, you'll need to use the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_domain_users) or [GAM](https://github.com/jay0lee/GAM/wiki/GAM3CSVListings#printing-all-users) to specify what data you want to pull down.

If you're populating AD, you'll want to look at implementing [GAPS](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2611859) so you can subsequently sync your passwords from LDAP > Apps once the users are provisioned. If you're using another type of LDAP, GADS can sync your passwords after the fact. The final option for passwords would be to implement an SSO solution to manage them in both systems.